# Identity $|\eta^i+\eta^j+\eta^k|=|\eta^{i+j}+\eta^{i+k}+\eta^{j+k}|$ where $\eta=e^{\frac{2\pi i}{5}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

If $\eta$ is a fifth root of unity and $i,j,k$ are integers, then

$$
|\eta^i+\eta^j+\eta^k|=|\eta^{i+j}+\eta^{i+k}+\eta^{j+k}| \tag{1} 
$$

I'm not satisfied with the proof I have so far, which is as follows : first, the identity is trivial if $\eta=1$, so we can assume that $\eta$ is a primitive fifth root of unity. Next, we may consider $i,j,k$ to be values modulo $5$. The identity at $(\eta,i,j,k)$ is equivalent to the identity at $(\eta,0,j-i,k-i)$, so we can assume $i=0$. Also, if $j\neq 0$, then the identity at $(\eta,0,j,k)$ is equivalent to the identity at $(\eta^j,0,1,\frac{k}{j})$,
so we may assume $j\in \lbrace 0,1 \rbrace$.

We are now left with ten cases (since $i=0$, and there are two possible values for $j$, five possible values for $k$) which can be checked one by one.

But surely, a simple identity like (1) must have better and less painstaking proofs ? Perhaps it has illuminating generalizations also ?

Comment: It's not really a problem here, but note that $\eta^i=(e^{2\pi i/5})^i=e^{2\pi i^2/5}=\cdots$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Your're confusing two distinct meanings for $i$ : the integer index and the complex square of $-1$

Comment: Yes, I know. I was just joking about the potential pitfalls of making one symbol serve two purposes. Sort of like asking for the number of primes less than or equal to $3.14159\ldots$.

Comment: You are unnecessarily overloading your notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One has
$$|u+v+w|=|uv+uw+vw|$$
whenever $|u|=|v|=|w|=1$. This is because
$$|uv+uw+vw|=|u||v||w||u^{-1}+v^{-1}+w^{-1}|
=|\overline u+\overline v+\overline w|=
|\overline{u+v+w}|=|u+v+w|.$$

Comment: Exactly what I was asking for!